# Diff files based on filename regardless of location

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I created a new project and seperated things out into different maven modules (projects/libraries if you are not familiar with maven).

Now I want to compare the file contents with another branch, but since the locations of the files are all changed I was hoping there was a way to do this based on the filenames.

i.e. if 2 files are the same name and extension, diff them and tell me if they are different.

I use git, and only at the command line level so I am hoping to use a gui since this will be a pain without it.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you want to use `git diff -- branchA:path/to/file1 branchB:another/path/to/file2`?

---

If you have simply renamed your files, you can try your luck with the `-M`/`--find-renames` options to [git diff](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-diff.html):

```
git diff -M branchA branchB --
```

Also have a look at `-C`/`--find-copies` and `-C -C`/`--find-copies-harder`

Comment: I have 100 files...looking for a bulk operation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install the diffmerge application and when you type git diff with given filename will open diffmerge tools where you can exactly see the diff.

```
git config --global diff.tool diffmerge
git config --global difftool.diffmerge.cmd "diffmerge \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$REMOTE\""

git config --global merge.tool diffmerge
git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd "diffmerge --merge --result=\"\$MERGED\"
 \"\$LOCAL\" \"\$BASE\" \"\$REMOTE\""
git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustexitcode false
```